# Does Ramsay Snow actually do this to Theon Greyjoy?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In game of thrones, s03e07,

> Theon is seen to be about to be sliced by Ramsay's men before the scene gets blurred.  In the succeeding episodes, there were no indications that Theon's manhood was really cut-off.  Is there any other parts in Game of Thrones that would prove that Theon's manhood was really cut off?

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the show, Yara Greyjoy receives a box from Ramsay Snow, and opens it to see it contains Theon's member. She then shows her father, Baylon. Baylon's unwillingness to retaliate is what led to Yara's failed attempt to rescue Theon from Moat Cailin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, though (for obvious reasons) the act itself is never shown on-screen, Ramsay quite definitively gelded Theon.

The scene begins with Theon being seduced by two of Ramsay's women, but only as part of Ramsay's torture plans. They make repeated comments about how well-endowed Theon is rumored to be. Once Ramsay comes in, he surmises that Theon's manhood is the part of his body he most treasures. He then pulls out a knife, and two men hold Theon down while Ramsay cuts him. (The knife is a gelding knife, the kind used to geld horses and, presumably, eunuchs.)

Later, Ramsay sends a package to Theon's family to show what's been done to Theon. Again, we never see the contents, but it's very strongly implied that it's Theon's castrated member in the box.

---

This is one case where the show is actually being more graphic than the novel. Ramsay's torture of Theon is revealed mostly through flashbacks much later, and not in as graphic detail. The piece of Theon that Ramsay sent to the Greyjoys is just described as a "piece of his flesh". The only indication in the novels we have about the castration, as @MikeyMouse points out, is when Theon admits that he can't have sex with Jeyne in front of Ramsay because he lacks the equipment.

Comment: Although in the books when Theon is with Ramsay consummating his wedding to Jeyne he tells Reek to get things started, to which Reek replied "I can't, I have no...." then Ramsay tells him to use his mouth.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that.

Comment: I'd managed to forget that, too! (Seriously. But the selective amnesia probably wasn't because of the inference of what had happened to Theon, but the explicit description of what was happening to Jeyne.  It was the one place, even in this long and gory narrative, where I felt that the author really had gone too far.  I couldn't continue to be immersed in the story, at least not for a while.)

Comment: Yeah, and they didn't do themselves and favors adapting that scene to the show, either, judging by the recent reaction. :\

Comment: There's also a scene that happens after the gelding with Ramsay eating a pork sausage that heavily implies that the deed has been done.

Comment: OK. Thanks for all your clarifications.  I just had to ask it because I have not seen all the scenes relating to Ramsay-Theon story.  And on the case that I have seen one, like for example when the Greyjoys receive the package, I was aware of that.  But what runs in my mind is that, maybe Ramsay was just messing with the minds of Greyjoys, like, what if the piece sent was not actually Theon's toy?  Then on the case of Theon, he didn't castrate him yet so that at any time, it could be Ramsay's threat to him if he disobeys.  This is logical storyline don't you think?

Comment: I think one thing we've seen about Ramsay is that he's as much of a sadist as his father, but lacks the restraint. Once he got Theon into the position to torture and castrate him, I doubt he would have had the ability to stop himself from carrying it out.